# How to print column headers along side table data from web to excel with webdriver

Tags: java, excel, selenium, webdriver, apache-poi

**Issue**
The below code allows me to either print column headers or print web table data into a csv file depending on if I chose 'th' or 'td' tags but not both simultaneously.

**My Question**
 How do I get it to print to csv both the 'th' and 'td' text at the same time in my CSV output??

**Code**
I have tried 2 versions of my code, but results are same.Both versions attached.

**Code Version 1**

```
public class WebToCSV {

static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable   {

        //driver.navigate().to("http://goo.gl/El1PIV");
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks/futures");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
                ("div[class='data-tables first']"));

        List<WebElement> irow = table.findElements
                (By.cssSelector("div[class='data-tables first']  tr"));
        System.out.println("No. of rows in the table are: " + irow.size());

        // Create excel workbook and sheet.
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream
                ("/Users/HARSHENDU/Desktop/Selenium_Practice/Stats.csv");

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.createSheet("WriteToXL");

        for(int r=0; r<irow.size(); r++) {
            WebElement webRow = irow.get(r);
            System.out.println(webRow.getText());
            XSSFRow row = ws.createRow(r);
            List<WebElement> allCells = webRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

            for(int c=0; c<allCells.size(); c++) {
                WebElement webCell = allCells.get(c);
                String text = webCell.getText();

                XSSFCell excelCell = row.createCell(c);
                excelCell.setCellValue(text);
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }

        fos.flush();
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();

        end();

}
    public static void end() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
```

}

**Code Version 2**
This version has 2 sets of for loops, first one to print column headers in csv, and second one to print all data from the webtable.

```
public class StatsToxL {

static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable   {

    //driver.navigate().to("http://goo.gl/El1PIV");
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks/futures");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("div[class='data-tables first']"));

    // Get webtable header column row.
    List<WebElement> irow2 = table.findElements
            (By.cssSelector("div[class='data-tables first'] thead tr "));
    System.out.println("No. of rows in the header are: " + irow2.size());

    // Get all webtable rows
    List<WebElement> irow = table.findElements
            (By.cssSelector("div[class='data-tables first'] tbody tr"));
    int iRowCount = irow.size();
    System.out.println("No. of rows in the table are: " + iRowCount);

    // Create excel workbook and sheet.
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream
            ("/Users/HARSHENDU/Desktop/Selenium_Practice/Stats.csv");

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet ws = wb.createSheet("WriteToXL");

    // Iterate over webtable header row and header cells.
    for(int r2=0; r2<irow2.size(); r2++) {
    WebElement webRow2 = irow2.get(r2);
        System.out.println(webRow2.getText());
        XSSFRow row2 = ws.createRow(r2);

        List<WebElement> allCells2 = webRow2.findElements(By.tagName("th"));

        for(int c2=0; c2<allCells2.size(); c2++) {
            WebElement webCell = allCells2.get(c2);
            String text2 = webCell.getText();
            XSSFCell excelCell2 = row2.createCell(c2);
            excelCell2.setCellValue(text2);

        }
        System.out.println("");
        fos.flush();
        wb.write(fos);
    }

    // Iterate over webtable rows and cells.
    for(int r=0; r<iRowCount; r++) {
        WebElement webRow = irow.get(r);
        System.out.println(webRow.getText());
        XSSFRow row = ws.createRow(r);
        List<WebElement> allCells = webRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

        for(int c=0; c<allCells.size(); c++) {
            WebElement webCell = allCells.get(c);
            String text = webCell.getText();

            XSSFCell excelCell = row.createCell(c);
            excelCell.setCellValue(text);
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }

    fos.flush();
    wb.write(fos);
    fos.close();

    end();

}
public static void end() {
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

Comment: If you are writing only a csv file, then using apache-poi to do it is a **huge** overkill! It's just a plain text file.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I originally chose poi because I was trying to get output in an xlsx file, but that file wouldn't open every time I ran the script.
Research said poi acts like that for xlsx and instead csv should be used.

As per your observation, I will try to do it with a buffered reader. I think that's what you meant. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
webRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"))
```

to

```
webRow.findElements(By.xpath("//td | //th"))
```